# Evaluate limit.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, continuity

Let $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be differentiable at $x = a$. Evaluate:

> $$ \lim_{n\to \infty}\large[{f(a +\frac{1}{n^2})}+{f(a +\frac{2}{n^2})}+...+{f(a +\frac{n}{n^2})}-nf(a)] $$
>   Answer: $\   $ $\ \frac{1}{2}f'(a)$

**My attempt**:
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty}\large[{f(a +\frac{1}{n^2})}-f(a)+{f(a +\frac{2}{n^2})}-f(a)+...+{f(a +\frac{n}{n^2})}- f(a)] $$
I don't know how to proceed from here? Please just give me hint. I want to solve this question by my self. Thank you.

Comment: Mean value theorem.

Comment: By the definition of the derivative, for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that for all $0 \leqslant h \leqslant \delta$ we have $\bigl(f'(a) - \varepsilon\bigr)h \leqslant f(a+h) - f(a) \leqslant \bigl(f'(a) + \varepsilon\bigr)h$.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla How is that going to help?

Comment: $f(a+k/n^2) - f(a) = f'(c_k)k/n^2$, $a<c_k<k/n^2$.

Comment: Forgot my hint. Works, but requires $f'$ continuous.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left\{f(c+\frac{1}{n^2})+f(c+\frac{2}{n^2})+\cdots+f(c+\frac{n}{n^2})-nf(c)\right\}=\frac{1}{2} f'(c)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1452406/how-to-show-that-lim-n-to-infty-left-fc-frac1n2fc-frac2n2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$[f(a+\frac{1}{n^2})-f(a)]+[f(a+\frac{2}{n^2})-f(a)]+\ldots +[f(a+\frac{n}{n^2})-f(a)]$

$=\dfrac{[f(a+\frac{1}{n^2})-f(a)]}{\frac{1}{n^2}}\times {\frac{1}{n^2}}+\dfrac{[f(a+\frac{2}{n^2})-f(a)]}{\frac{2}{n^2}}\times {\frac{2}{n^2}}+\ldots +\dfrac{[f(a+\frac{n}{n^2})-f(a)]}{\frac{1}{n^2}}\times {\frac{n}{n^2}}$

$=\sum _{i=1}^n [f(a+\frac{k}{n^2})-f(a)]{\frac{k}{n^2}}$

Note that $\lim_{n\to \infty }\dfrac{[f(a+\frac{k}{n^2})-f(a)]}{\frac{k}{n^2}}=f^{'}(a)\to (1)$

**ADDED**:Following $(1)$;Given $\epsilon>0;\exists m $ such that $n\ge m\implies|\dfrac{[f(a+\frac{k}{n^2})-f(a)]}{{\frac{k}{n^2}}}-f^{'}(a)|<\epsilon\implies $

$(f^{'}(a)-\epsilon)\dfrac{k}{n^2}\le [f(a+\frac{k}{n^2})-f(a)]\le(f^{'}(a)-\epsilon)\dfrac{k}{n^2}\forall k$

Summing over $k$ for all $k=1,2,\ldots n$ we have $(f^{'}(a)-\epsilon)\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2n^2}\le \sum_{k=1}^n[f(a+\frac{k}{n^2})-f(a)]\le(f^{'}(a)-\epsilon)\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2n^2}$

Hence the above expression reduces to $f^{'}(a)[\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2n^2}]\to \dfrac{1}{2}f^{'}(a)$ as $n\to \infty$

@kccu ;Look at the *ADDED* part to clear your doubts

Comment: Oh brother. Thank you so much. Why couldn't I see that?

Comment: @user114873 because it's a tricky problem :) don't beat yourself up about it!

Comment: You can consider accepting it if it fits you@user114873

Comment: Doesn't this sweep things under the rug a bit by saying "the above expression reduces to..."? They are not actually equal, you have taken the limit of some pieces of the sum. What's to say that is okay? If I want to find $\lim_{n \to \infty} 1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}$, I can't say "each piece goes to $0$ so the sum is $0$." Yours is a nice heuristic explanation, but I think it needs more justification.

Comment: @kccu;You can have a look now;

Comment: @learnmore I corrected some typos. It still isn't quite right to say "the above expression reduces to...". Now you want to take the limit of all three parts of the inequality to get $(f'(a)-\epsilon) \cdot \frac{1}{2} \leq \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n f(a+\frac{k}{n^2}-f(a)) \leq (f'(a)+\epsilon) \cdot \frac{1}{2}$. (This requires justification - the limit holds as $n$ goes to infinity because it holds for all sufficiently large $n$.) Finally, argue that this holds for all $\epsilon>0$, so we can conclude the limit is actually equal to $\frac{1}{2}f'(a)$.

Comment: @learnmore I'm sure you are aware of these subtleties, but OP (and other readers) might not be, and it's important to understand what sorts of steps are allowed in taking limits.

Comment: @kccu;I believe that you need to fill up the missing parts yourself in an answer in order to learn from it which must be the case for everyone including the OP;If you still have doubts,then contact the answerer again

Comment: @learnmore You're right, answers here shouldn't always solve the problem in full detail, but I was taking issue with your saying "the above expression reduces to..." because it does not.

Answer (score 3):

From [Taylor's Theorem with the Peano remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor's_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem),

> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{f(a+k/n^2)-f(a)=f'(a)\frac k{n^2}+h(k/n^2)\frac k{n^2}} \tag 1$$

where $\displaystyle \lim_{k/n^2\to 0}h(k/n^2)=0$.

---

Using $(1)$, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n f(a+k/n^2)-nf(a)&=\frac1{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n kf'(a)+\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^nkh(k/n^2)\\\\
&=\frac{n(n+1)}{2n^2}f'(a)+\frac1{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n kh(k/n^2) \tag 2
\end{align}$$

It is easy to see that the limit of the first term on the right-hand side of $(2)$ is $\frac12f'(a)$.

---

Next, note that for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists a number $\delta(\epsilon)>0$ such that for $k/n^2<\delta(\epsilon)$, $|h(k/n^2)|\le \epsilon$.  Therefore, given $\epsilon>0$,

$$\left|\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n kh(k/n^2)\right|<\epsilon \frac{n(n+1)}{2n^2}\le \epsilon$$

whenever $k/n^2\le 1/n<\delta$.

---

Therefore, we have

> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{n\to \infty }\sum_{k=1}^n f(a+k/n^2)-nf(a)=\frac12 f'(a)}$$

And we are done!