# Evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \big \{ f(a+1/n^2)+f(a+2/n^2)+\cdots+f(a+n/n^2)-nf(a) \big\}$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> Given  $f$ : $\mathbb {R} \to \mathbb {R}$ be differentiable at $x=a$. Evaluate:
>   $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \big \{ f(a+1/n^2)+f(a+2/n^2)+\cdots+f(a+n/n^2)-nf(a)         \big\}.$$
>   Can I apply the theorem stated: $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)= \int_0^1 f(x) \, dx$$

Comment: $ f$ need not be integrable

Comment: how to approach?

Comment: Sorry but where do you see some $f(k/n)$ in the question?

Comment: I have no idea about the same @Did

Comment: Hmmm... What do you think the differentiability at $a$ could be helpful for? What is the definition of being differentiable at $a$, already?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Must there always be one definite area under the curve?

Comment: see also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1452406/how-to-show-that-lim-n-to-infty-left-fc-frac1n2fc-frac2n2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$. Then there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\left|\frac{f(a+h)-f(h)}{h}-f'(a)\right|<\epsilon$ for all $h$ with $|h|<\delta.$
For all $n>\frac1\delta$, we have $0<\frac k{n^2}\le\frac 1n<\delta$ for $1\le k\le n$, hence
$$f(a+k/n^2)-f(n)=\frac k{n^2}(f'(a)+ \epsilon_{k,n})\qquad\text{with }|\epsilon_{k,n}|<\epsilon $$
Then 
$$ \sum_{k=1}^nf(a+k/n^2)\;-nf(a)=\frac{f'(a)\sum_{k=1}^nk}{n^2}+\frac{\sum_kk\epsilon_{k,n}}{n^2}$$
The absolute value of the last term is $<\frac{\sum k}{n^2}\epsilon=\frac{n+1}{2n}\epsilon\le \epsilon$ and the first term is $\frac{n+1}{2n}f'(a)$ and tends to $\frac 12f'(a)$ as $n\to \infty$.
We conclude that 
$$ \left|\left(\sum_{k=1}^nf(a+k/n^2)\;-nf(a)\right)-\frac12f'(a)\right|<2\epsilon\qquad \text{for all }n\gg0.$$
As $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, we cconclude 
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum_{k=1}^nf(a+k/n^2)\;-nf(a)\right)=\frac12 f'(a).$$

*Remark:* Note that we reall yused nothing except differntiability at $a$. Indeed, $f$ may be discontinuous at all other points.